# spring-boot fails to load liquibase change on gradle build

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am using Spring-boot 1.1.1.RELEASE and I have an H2 database that is created at startup.  When I run my main class from IntelliJ, all works well. When I run with "***gradle build test***"  I get errors on my integration tests:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.checkChangelogExists(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'

project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.1.1.RELEASE'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.1.RELEASE")

    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'my-app'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.0.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.1.RELEASE')

    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.0.RC1")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.4.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.4.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")

    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.3")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1')
    compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1')
    compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spock-core'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-test'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

I have in both src/main/resources and src/test/resources an application.properties file that contains the following entry:

```
liquibase.changeLog=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

And then in both src/main/resources/db/changelog and src/test/resources/db/changelog  I have a **db.changelog-master.xml**   When I build the project, I see that **build/resources/test** and **build/resources/main** have the **application.properties, db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml** there.

This would appear to be a classpath issue, since it works from within IntelliJ and not the commandline.  Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: I agree that it sounds like a classpath problem. After you've run "gradle build" what's in build/resources/main and build/resources/test?

Comment: I have both master and build: /build/resources/.../db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml, build/resources/.../application.properties in addition to the other expected files.   So, everything is being placed there.

Comment: I assume you haven't customised Gradle's test task at all to change its classpath? Perhaps you could share a project somewhere that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the entire project.  And my build.gradle file doesn't have any test specific tasks on it.  I did update my post with the my gradle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see spock on the test classpath, so probably it's not using the right test context loader still (I wish they'd fix that). You need to add the loader or an initializer manually to your `@ContextConfiguration`. [Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-test-utilities).

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to add my fix here (even though my build is Maven). My `application.properties` was in my root directory, but it would not find my `db.changelog.xml` classpath as directed from the root directory. It needed the classpath to be from my `/resources` directory. Maybe I have my `application.properties` in an unconventional location, but I thought it was to be put in the root directory.

#### My Fix

**Though the actual path from my `application.properties` is this:**
`liquibase.change-log=classpath:/src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml`

**It needed this path to find it:**
`liquibase.change-log=classpath:/liquibase/db.changelog.xml`